# Aspect oriented sample projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, aop

I am looking ASP.NET MVC project samples which is designed in AOP fashion and use heavily interceptors. Are there any good samples ?

Answer (score 2):

Uh... every one of them?

MVC has tons of AOP style hooks.

When you strart understanding action filters and action invokers you don't need any sort of AOP libraries at all.

Comment: But i wanted to see usage interceptors how it is usefull on service layer. But surely filters provide some intercepting mechanism on presentation layer. I am also not intersted in AOP frameworks. Just DI container's interceptor mechanism which is not restricted by controller.

Comment: @AnyOne, not all MVC projects have a service layer.

Comment: @AnyOne - I'm trying to point out you asked the wrong question.  You are looking for AoP examples that have nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I using MS Unity + Policy injection: see good descriptions in three articles by Dino Esposito in [MSDN_Magazine1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490353.aspx) - [MSDN_Magazine2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg535676.aspx) - [MSDN_Magazine3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598927.aspx).

I use aspects for security check and caching of repository.

PS As far as I known every modern IoC-container supports AOP and if you use one yet you could check its aop-abilities.